# Server 2008R2 losing mapped drive to XP machine

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 Web Server R2, with a mapped drive G:  to an XP computer.
The server has a 24/7/365 chart generation application that reads data from the XP computer. The mapped drive
properly reconnects on a reboot, the application runs and produces charts fine,
until some time several hours later it hangs up, because the mapped drive has
disappeared.  When this happens  a command line dir g: hangs up and does not complete.
No error message from it, and the command prompt window can not be closed.
The server will not shut down, and the machine has to be reset or powered off to
restore the server.  Before this error occurs, shutdown and restart work properly.

This setup has run for years on a Windows 2000 server, with the application accessing
the same XP data machine.

A batch file doing netstat to a log file shows that the XP connection as
Vega3:microsoft-ds .  On the Windows 2000 machine it shows Vega3:netbios-ssn.

I have implemented the registry changes as suggested in Microsoft KB297684,
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297684 , on both the XP and 2008R2 computers
to no avail.

The server has two NIC's. I swapped which NIC was used for LAN and which for
the Server website static IP's.  It had no affect.

The event log does not show any related events.

I am not using active directory.  This is just a simple LAN setup using basic Windows
networking.

Any clues about what to look at next would be GREATLY appreciated.  Been battling this
tecnocrap for two weeks.

Comment: It is probably an issue with smb1, or lanman protocol. There are some registry tags you can tweak on the win2008 box to enable older protocols, and this can increase happiness. I have had success solving this kind of thing in some cases, and failures in others (and just have to reboot the system every couple weeks).

Comment: once the drive disconnects, can you still access the data via UNC? Check the event log on the 2008 server too.  I agree with @samsmith about the lanman settings in the registry.  Does your app support UNCs?  If so, that might be one workaround instead of worrying about a mapped drive.

Comment: In my experience with this problem (between a win2003 and win2000 server), unc does not work. It is a full connectivity problem, not just a drive letter issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  When the connection was lost, UNC did not work.  What seems to have fixed this problem is setting the NIC to not negotiate speed with the switch.  The switch is an older 10/100 MBit and the NIC is 10/100/1GB. I set it to 100Mbit and it has run for 4 days solid with a test script checking the connection every 5 minutes.

Comment: I also found out that a local hosting company tells everyone who sets up a machine in their data center to set all NICS to a fixed speed and turn off all auto negotiate.  So that seems like a good practice.